# R: rworldmap map issue and leaflet application

Tags: r, leaflet, rworldmap

I have made a leaflet map to overlay some countries on a R leaflet webmap, however there seems to be something wrong with the projection/layout and part of Russia finds it way onto the adjacent frame. 
[image]

The code:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(countrycode)



## country is in text 
cnt <- c("Russia","Afghanistan", "Albania"," Algeria"," Argentina","   Armenia", "Azerbaijan"," Bangladesh"," Belarus")


#convert to ISO3 code
iso3 = countrycode(cnt, "country.name", "iso3c")

df= as.data.frame(cnt)
malMap <- joinCountryData2Map(df, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "cnt")

## subset data
dfapr <- malMap[malMap$ISO3 %in% iso3, ]
plot(dfapr)
```

The main consequence of this problem is that if you are making a web-map it would look like this:[image]

How do we fix this problem. Is any any low resolution world map, wherein we can select the countries based on ISO code and is geometrically more consistent.

Comment: Just use another source for the shapefile. That one has the peninsula cropped and moved to avoid other "spatial" issues in R (like projection issues).

Comment: hrbrmstr , thank you. that's what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of what I meant by the comment.

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(leaflet)

# make sure to use the latest maps package
# it was recently updated at the time of the answer

world <- map("world", fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
world_map <- map2SpatialPolygons(world, sub(":.*$", "", world$names))
world_map <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(world_map,
                                      data.frame(country=names(world_map), 
                                                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
                                      FALSE)

cnt <- c("Russia", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Argentina", "Armenia",
         "Azerbaijan", "Bangladesh", "Belarus")

target <- subset(world_map, country %in% cnt)

leaflet(target) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(weight=1)
```

[image]